# Google Search console is showing errors in hreflang tags from another site in my international targeting report

Tags: google-search-console, hreflang

Received message from GWT(GSC): **Errors in hreflang tags on** site.com.

> We found the hreflang tags on your site, but a few of them have
>   technical problems. Take a look at our hreflang report to see which of
>   your hreflang tags have issues. Until you fix these tag errors, your
>   website will not benefit from additional language or region targeting.

By link from mail <kbd>See hreflang errors</kbd> i get this page:

[image]

But my site isn't multi-language! When I click on any line from GWT(GSC) errors list i get links to **external multi-language site** which linked from my site! Looks like Google bot associate this external domain with my site. How to fix?

Comment: I've never seen Google do anything like that before.   It sounds like a Google bug, I'm not sure there is anything you can do.